# Select everything with a statement, then echo specific rows

Tags: php, mysql

I have a select statement that grabs a full table from a database.

```
if ($select = $db -> prepare("SELECT service_id, service_name, service_cost FROM services"))
{
    $select -> execute();
    $select -> bind_result($service_id, $service_name, $service_cost);
    $select -> fetch();
    $select -> close();
}
```

(I know I can use `query` instead of `prepare` in this example.)

Outputs

```
service_id  |  service_name  |  service_cost 
1              Artwork          80.00
2              Printing         60.00
3              Binding          20.00
4              Finishing        30.00
```

So now that I have all of the data from the services table at my disposal, I want to be able to echo certain things in certain places. Let's say I want to echo the service with the ID of 2 which is Printing somewhere on my page and maybe the cost of Printing further down my page. Is there a way of doing this without having to write two new statements with `WHERE id=?` just to get those?

Something like `echo $service_name(2)` where 2 is the ID?

Does something similar to this exist?

What is the best practice to accomplish what I am trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution is this:

```
if ($select = $db -> prepare("SELECT service_id, service_name, service_cost FROM services"))
{
    $select -> execute();
    $select -> bind_result($service_id, $service_name, $service_cost);
    $select -> fetch();
    while ($stmt->fetch()) {
        if($service_id==2)       
        {
             printf("%s %s\n", $service_name, $service_cost);
        }
    }
    $select -> close();
}
```

but maybe you want to make it like this (Assuming id is unique):

```
function print_query_variable($id, $variable_name)
{
if ($select = $db -> prepare("SELECT service_id, service_name, service_cost FROM services WHERE service_id=$id"))
{
    $select->execute();
    $select->bind_result($service_id, $service_name, $service_cost);
    $select->fetch();
    $select->fetch();
    $select->close();
    return $$variable_name;
}

}
```

Comment: You're using a prepared statement yet you've still included unsanitized `$id` as a part of the query..

Comment: I am using a unique ID, so I am using your bottom example exactly as it is (I will sanitize $id myself). When I put `print_query_variable('2', 'service_name');` on my page I get "Call to a member function prepare() on null in..." which when var_dumped says its missing both arguments.

Comment: yes, of course you have to init your $db object as you did before your if

Comment: I do have the DB initialized prior to the code. If I take away the function, the query works fine. For some reason, it is not finding the arguments I put into the function.

Comment: I see what you meant. The DB needs to be called inside the function. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can transform your data to behave just like you want:

```
$services = array();
foreach ($result as $r) {
    $services[$r['service_id']] = $r;
}
```

Now you can get information by ID:

```
$id = 2;
echo $services[$id]['service_name'];
```